CSS variables not working with Tailwind CSS custom color variables
Ever since I started doing this:
tailwind.config.ts:
primary: {
  DEFAULT: 'var(--primary)',
  foreground: '#404040',
},

globals.css:
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

:root, .theme-light {
  --foreground: #404040;
  --background: #ffffff;
  --primary: #c1df87;
  --muted: #787878;
  --subtle: #f2f2f2;
  --border: #b2b2b2;
}

Stuff like this has stopped working:
default: 'hover:bg-primary/90',

So in this example, the button won't change its background color if you hover it.

If you want to support the color opacity syntax with custom colors, you can't define them with hex codes. See the documentation on this here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#using-css-variables
Declare your color with standalone rgb values like:
--primary: 123 200 123;

And in your config declare your color like:
DEFAULT: 'rgb(var(--primary) / <alpha-value>)'

And now it works as expected. See it working on tailwind play here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/QXuv37mpra
